# CMake: Convert relative path to absolute path or the cmake command line arguments

Tags: cmake

I'm running my cmake (3.16) from outside the source. Usually with these arguments

```
cmake -S ./avionics_apps/ -B build -DINPUT_DIR:PATH=./other-build/
```

What is the way to convert the relative path set in `INPUT_DIR` variable to the absolute path that would equally work for out and in source builds? `get_filename_component` can be used, but it requires some base path. However, I couldn't yet find a variable in cmake that specifies the directory from which cmake was *run*. There are binary and source directories. But the in-source build the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` are the same.

Comment: Maybe an example of what the problem is would be useful.  INPUT_DIR should be converted to an absolute path automatically.  Are you saying that isn't happening?  If you want to store the current working directory why not use `-DCWD=\`pwd\``?

Comment: INPUT_DIR should be converted to an absolute path automatically? It isn't happening. Inside the code it looks the same as passed. Using `-DCWD='pwd'` might work, but I was hoping that CMake has something already.

Comment: @Tsyvarev From the CMake documentation for `cmake(1)` for `-D`:
`If a command in the project sets the type to PATH or FILEPATH then the <value> will be converted to an absolute path.`  From the `set` command ` Furthermore, if the <type> is PATH or FILEPATH and the <value> provided on the command line is a relative path, then the set command will treat the path as relative to the current working directory and convert it to an absolute path.` Perhaps I misunderstood of when or how the conversion takes place.

Comment: @fdk1342: You are right! The most difficult part was to understand that a variable's type should NOT be specified in the command line...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @fdk1342 for the hint. How the automatic conversion can be achieved:

1. When pass the variable via command line, do **not specify** its **type**:

   ```
   -DINPUT_DIR=./other-build/
   ```
2. When declare the variable in `CMakeLists.txt`, do **specify** type as PATH or FILEPATH

   ```
   set(INPUT_DIR "" CACHE PATH "Input directory")
   ```

   Implicit creation of CACHE variable works too:

   ```
   find_path(INPUT_DIR foo.h)
   ```

When **both conditions** are fulfilled, a value of the variable will be automatically converted into the **absolute path**.

Actually, this is described in the description of the [set command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/set.html):

> It is possible for the cache entry to exist prior to the call but have no type set if it was created on the `cmake(1)` command line by a user through the `-D<var>=<value>` option without specifying a type. In this case the `set` command will add the type. Furthermore, if the `<type>` is PATH or FILEPATH and the `<value>` provided on the command line is a relative path, then the `set` command will treat the path as relative to the current working directory and convert it to an absolute path.