# Why is CMake install directory different in CLion vs. outside CLion?

Tags: cmake, clion

I am learning CMake; [my learning material](https://www.udemy.com/course/effective-modern-cmake-level-beginner/) is based around CLion and its native integration with CMake. But I also like to reinforce my learning by doing the same things by invoking `cmake` with appropriate arguments from the command-line, so that my learning is not tightly coupled to an IDE. While learning about installing CMake projects, I observed a discrepancy in the destination directory when installation is done from the CLion IDE versus when done from the command line. I would like to understand why this discrepancy exists, because my understanding is that IDE integrations with CMake are ultimately just wrappers around CLI invocations of CMake, so ultimately, a user should be able to see consistent behavior between the IDE and outside of it.

Screenshots, and text of those screenshots are below the question details, to keep this post better organized.

I downloaded CLion, with a 30-day trial from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/download/#section=windows).
I did not install any plugins or any form of add-ons.

I am trying to build googletest-release-1.11.0 from source, with CMake, in the CLion IDE.
I downloaded googletest-release-1.11.0 from [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.11.0) to `C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0`.

In the `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake` settings of the CLion IDE, I configure:

- Build type: Release
- Generator: Ninja
- CMake options: `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="install-dir" -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON`

When I reload the CMake project, the following `cmake.exe` invocation is revealed in the CMake window:
`"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.3/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install-dir -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON -G Ninja -S C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0 -B C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release`

When I click `Build > Build All in 'Release'` the project, the following `cmake.exe` invocation is revealed in the Messages window: `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target all -j 18`

And when I click `Build > Install`, the following `cmake.exe` invocation is revealed in the Messages window: `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target install -j 18`

Note (from the screenshot below) that the install directory is `C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/`, which is a subdirectory of the *binary directory*.

But when I repeat these same three commands from a Windows Command Prompt, the install directory is `C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/`, which is a subdirectory of the *source directory*.

My question is: **why is the install directory different when run from the CLion IDE versus when run outside the IDE, even though I'm building the same project, from the same source directory with the same `cmake.exe` invocations?**
I would really like to understand why the same commands results in different behavior when invoked by CLion vs. when run outside of CLion.

I note that in the configurations performed above, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is specified as a relative path, but as far as I can make out, the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) doesn't say explicitly what the behavior should be with respect to relative paths and/or any relationship to the source directory versus the binary directory.

---

Screenshots

[image: CMake settings in CLion IDE]

[image: CMake configuration/generation stage]

[image: Build from CLion IDE]

[image: Install from CLion IDE]

[image: CMake configuration/generation, build, and install from Command Prompt]

---

If it helps, below is the text of the above screenshots, in the same order:

CMake configuration/generation stage from the CLion IDE:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.3/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install-dir -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON -G Ninja -S C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0 -B C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33134.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33134.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at googlemock/CMakeLists.txt:45 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at googletest/CMakeLists.txt:56 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) 
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done (9.5s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release

[Finished]
```

Build from CLion IDE:

```
====================[ Build | all | Release ]===================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target all -j 18
[1/11] Building CXX object googletest\CMakeFiles\gtest_main.dir\src\gtest_main.cc.obj
[2/11] Building CXX object googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock_main.dir\src\gmock_main.cc.obj
[3/11] Building CXX object googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock.dir\src\gmock-all.cc.obj
[4/11] Building CXX object googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock_main.dir\src\gmock-all.cc.obj
[5/11] Building CXX object googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock.dir\__\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc.obj
[6/11] Building CXX object googletest\CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\src\gtest-all.cc.obj
[7/11] Linking CXX static library lib\gmock.lib
[8/11] Linking CXX static library lib\gtest.lib
[9/11] Linking CXX static library lib\gtest_main.lib
[10/11] Building CXX object googlemock\CMakeFiles\gmock_main.dir\__\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc.obj
[11/11] Linking CXX static library lib\gmock_main.lib

Build finished
```

Install from CLion IDE:

```
====================[ Install | Release ]=======================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target install -j 18
[0/1] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-cardinalities.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-nice-strict.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/gmock.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/gmock_main.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gmock.pc
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gmock_main.pc
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets.cmake
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets-release.cmake
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-message.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-spi.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest_prod.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-filepath.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port-arch.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-string.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/gtest.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/gtest_main.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gtest.pc
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gtest_main.pc

Install finished
```

CMake configuration/generation, build, and install from Command Prompt:

```
c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.3/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install-dir -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON -G Ninja -S C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0 -B C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33134.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.38.33134.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at googlemock/CMakeLists.txt:45 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at googletest/CMakeLists.txt:56 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done (8.6s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release

c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target all -j 18
[11/11] Linking CXX static library lib\gmock_main.lib

c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0>"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target install -j 18
[0/1] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-cardinalities.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-nice-strict.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/gmock.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gmock/internal/gmock-pp.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/gmock.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/gmock_main.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gmock.pc
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gmock_main.pc
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets.cmake
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets-release.cmake
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-message.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-spi.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/gtest_prod.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-filepath.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port-arch.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-string.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/gtest.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/gtest_main.lib
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gtest.pc
-- Installing: C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/lib/pkgconfig/gtest_main.pc
```

---

Update: Trying to explore @Tsyvarev's answer, I tried the following:

1. `cd c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\`
2. Run CMake configure/generate (using the same command revealed from the CLion IDE): `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.3/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install-dir -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON -G Ninja -S C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0 -B C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release`
3. Build (using the same command revealed from the CLion IDE): `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target all -j 18`
4. Install (using the same command revealed from the CLion IDE): `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target install -j 18`

Result: installation still happens to `C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/install-dir/` instead of the expected `C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/`.

---

Update: I can achieve the consistency of behavior between CLion and non-CLion by doing the following:

1. `mkdir c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-result`
2. `cd c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-result`
3. Run CMake configure/generate (using the same command revealed from the CLion IDE): `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.3/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install-dir -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON -G Ninja -S C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0 -B C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release`
4. Build (using the same command revealed from the CLion IDE): `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target all -j 18`
5. Install (using the same command revealed from the CLion IDE): `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\cmake-build-release --target install -j 18`

Result: installation now happens to `C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0/cmake-build-release/install-dir/`.

I guess this means CLion is behind-the-scenes doings steps 1 and 2, and maintaining that created directory as the CWD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic here: You specify a **relative path** for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` parameter, so CMake interprets it relative to the **current working directory** and automatically transforms it to the absolute path. Internal mechanism is described in that my answer: [CMake: Convert relative path to absolute path or the cmake command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787104/cmake-convert-relative-path-to-absolute-path-or-the-cmake-command-line-argument).

When `cmake` is run from CLion IDE, the current working director is the build one: note that CLion specifies source directory with `-S` parameter but doesn't specify  `-B` parameter, assuming build directory to be the current one. That is, the relative path in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is interpreted against the build directory.

But when you run `cmake` from Command Prompt, the current working directory is `C:/libs/googletest-release-1.11.0`. So the relative path in `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is interpreted against this directory.

Comment: This answer looked promising, but I couldn't reproduce the expected behavior. "note that CLion specifies source directory with `-S` parameter but doesn't specify `-B` parameter" -- am I missing something that you're pointing out? I see both `-S` and `-B` arguments for the CMake generation. Anyhow, I tried this: 1) run the CMake generation command (which creates the `cmake-build-release/` subdirectory, 2) cd to the `cmake-build-release/` directory, 3) run the build and install commands. Result: installation still happens in `c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\install-dir`...

Comment: ... instead of `c:\libs\googletest-release-1.11.0\install-dir`. I would therefore _guess_ that the `cmake-build-release/` subdirectory must be being created by CLion, i.e. not by the CMake configure/generate command. Then CLion runs _even the CMake configure/generate_ from the subdirectory_. That's my _guess_ -- I wonder, do you know this is correct? (Perhaps this is what your answer is already stating, I just wasn't clear about that specific point: does CLion create the subdirectory itself, then make that the CWD, or does it rely on the CMake configure/generate to create the subdirectory)

Comment: "Build directory is always created manually, not by CMake" -- my experience has been different: when I run CMake configure/generate with `cmake -B /path/to/foo ...`, then `/path/to/foo/` is created. Tutorials I have read so far teach "given `c:\proj\src\CMakeLists.txt`, run `cmake -S c:\proj\src -B c:\proj\build`", which therefore creates the `build` subdirectory. But in the context of the post, it seems CLion is creating the `build` subdirectory and then maintaining there as the CWD.

Comment: ...But I think the gist of your answer is correct: CLion must be creating the build directory (maybe more correct to call it the "binary directory" in CMake terminology) instead of relying on `cmake -B` to create it, and then maintains that created directory as the CWD for all subsequent CMake operations. I just wish there was a way to confirm this, or that CLion would make this more explicit.

Comment: Oh, yes, with `-B` CMake may create the build directory automatically. I forget about that aspect as I usually run `cmake` with other command flow, which requires to be run from the build directory. CLion is actually passes `-B` option, I missed that fact on my previous readings of your question. So we can only guess which directory is CWD in case of CLion.